# Ready API 2.2.0 skip SSLHandShakeException

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, soapui, sslhandshakeexception, ready-api

I work in  ***Ready Api 2.2.0*** and I have tests which do not fail when a certificate is invalid on the server side (although simple java tests fail as expected). I need that as negative cases.

My question is:

***Why ready API skip handshake exception and how to force the tool to receive it?***

Comment: Hi Olya!  may I suggest you tag this with the [soap-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soapui) tag as it seems also soap-ui related and possibly someone with more knowledge of SOAP-UI might be able to help - I only suggest as googling for your issue a ton of soap ui results came up - and unfortunately googling did not show how to answer your question

Comment: @JGlass good advise, did so,thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome!  If you figure out the answer - answer your own question with it! You might also post it in [soap ui forums](https://community.smartbear.com/) as a lot of people had problems with the ssl not being verified in various versions.  Maybe try a newer (or older) version?